# "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to List<Item>" when sorting with Comparator

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a list of Items such that items with category "Games" are at the bottom of the list.

I am getting the error in the title. what am i doing wrong?

```
public static void write(List<Item> dontExist2) {

        List<Item> dontExist3 = Collections.sort(dontExist2, new Comparator<Item>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
                String cat1 = o1.getCategory();
                String cat2 = o2.getCategory();
                if (cat1.contains("Games")) {
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort returns void, it sorts the list dontExist2 you pass as a parameter. After the call, the list will be sorted.

Comment: how does it know which field to sort by? its not a list of strings its list of object `Item`

Comment: According to your comparator of course. That's the whole point here.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: @user521180 You have an anonymous `Comparator` that you passed as an argument. The sort method will use it to sort the list you also passed as an argument.

Comment: Exactly what @SotiriosDelimanolis said

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so what's the problem?

Comment: The `Collections.sort()` method returns void. Don't assign that statement to `List<Item> dontExist3`. It's already sorted `dontExist2` internally. This is exactly what @Avi said.